# How to Remove the Facebook share Button from ADDTHIS API

Tags: facebook, api, magento, addthis

**`<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button"></a>`**

I added Above line to show facebook like. it showing like button , 
but unfortunately its showing like button with the share button. how can i remove the share button from the line. i need only facebook like button. please help me

Comment: `button` sounds like they are just using the "original" FB Like button `layout` setting and passing the value on. The valid values are listed here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button#settings

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count" fb:like:action="recommend" fb:like:width="135"></a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Having the same issue with , share button located near like button

Comment: Ok i will check that and reply u for that.

Comment: Thank you for that , i thought for is with like button.

Comment: i need to remove the share button @Amit Udale

Comment: Its not for its Problem above

Comment: is there anyway to remove the facebook share button.

Comment: U can get your ans

Comment: https://hc.weebly.com/hc/en-us/articles/202081836-Add-a-Facebook-Like-Button-to-Your-Site

Comment: i need only customize addthis API. not including new one!